# ElasticSearch geo distance filter with multiple locations in array - possible?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say we have a bunch of documents in an ElasticSearch index. Each documents has multiple locations *in an array*, like this:

```
{
  "name": "foobar",
  "locations": [
    {
      "lat": 40.708519,
      "lon": -74.003212
    },
    {
      "lat": 39.752609,
      "lon": -104.998100
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.506321,
      "lon": -0.127140
    }
  ]
}
```

According to the [ElasticSearch reference guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/geo-distance-filter/)

> the `geo_distance` filter can work with multiple locations / points
>   per document. Once a single location / point matches the filter, the
>   document will be included in the filter.

So, is it possible to create a geo distance filter which checks all the locations in the array?

This doesn't seem to work, unfortunately:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "geo_distance": {
      "distance": "100 km",
      "locations": "40, -105"
    }
  }
}
```

throws "`QueryParsingException[[myIndex] failed to find geo_point field [locations]`" since `locations` is not a single `geo_point` but an array of `geo_point`s.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Did you specify a [geo_point mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/geo-point-type/) for your document?

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_mapping' -d '
{
    "tweet" : {
        "properties" : {
            "locations" : {"type" : "geo_point"}
        }
    }
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1' -d '
{ 
    "user": "kimchy", 
    "postDate": "2009-11-15T13:12:00", 
    "message": "Trying out Elastic Search, so far so good?",
    "locations" : [{
        "lat" : 50.00,
        "lon" : 10.00
    },
    {
        "lat" : 40.00,
        "lon" : 9.00
    }]
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/2' -d '
{ 
    "user": "kimchy", 
    "postDate": "2009-11-15T13:12:00", 
    "message": "Trying out Elastic Search, so far so good?",
    "locations" : [{
        "lat" : 30.00,
        "lon" : 8.00
    },
    {
        "lat" : 20.00,
        "lon" : 7.00
    }]
}'

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search' -d '{
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "20km",
                    "tweet.locations" : {
                        "lat" : 40.00,
                        "lon" : 9.00
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Then it should work, see my example. Which ES version do you use? I tested it on 0.20.6.

Comment: Actually, it *does* work now after nuking the original index. Specifying a geo_point mapping and then just inserting an array of locations did the trick, my previous mapping was way too complex. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Will this work with the fast bbox filter `geo_bounding_box` ? `geo_distance` is probably slower (because of the radius distance math). I will try this with `{"type": "geo_point", "lat_lon": true}`

Comment: Hi, the example didn't work now in ES v1.7.3. The locations field is always empty if I insert array of values. Is there any thing changed?

Answer (score 5):

For Elasticsearch version 5.1, for same above index, query will go like this,

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": "200km",
                    "locations": {
                        "lat": 40.00,
                        "lon": 9.00
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```