# Elasticsearch - MySQL Index Search Distance Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am trying to use Elasticsearch indexed on a MySQL table to find all addresses that are within x km from a particular data point. I have indexed the table with the following:

```
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "jdbc": {
       "strategy": "simple",
       "url": "jdbc:mysql://hostname/databasename",
       "user": "username",
       "password": "password",
       "sql": "SELECT name,address1,city,state,zip,lat as `location.lat`,lng as `location.lon` FROM addresses",
       "poll": "24h",
       "max_retries": 3,
       "max_retries_wait": "10s",
       "index" : "teststores",
       "type" : "providers"
   },
   "index": {
       "index": "addressindex",
       "autocommit": "true",
       "type": "mysql",
       "bulk_size": 100,
       "type_mapping": {
           "location_mapping" : { 
                "properties" : {
                    "pin" : {
                        "type" : "geo_point"
                    }
                }       
            }
        }
   }
}
```

An example of the indexed data is the following:

```
"_index": "teststores",
"_type": "providers",
"_id": "Rue2Yxo7SSa_mi5-AzRycA",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
    "zip": "10003",
    "name": "I Salon",
    "state": "NY",
    "address1": "150 East 14th Street",
    "location":{
                "lat": 40.7337,
                "lon": -73.9881
               },
    "city": "New York"
}
```

I want to adjust the following query to use lat and lng for calculating the distance.

```
{ 
  "query": {
       "filtered": {
       "query": {
          "match_all": {
           }
        },
        "filter": {
           "geo_distance" : {
               "distance" : "2km",
               "pin.location" : {
                    "lat" : 40.686511,
                    "lon" : -73.986574
                }
            }
        }
     }
  },
}
```

How can I adjust this to make the distance work and get all addresses within x kilometers?

Comment: Have you defined a [mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) for your [geo_point](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html#mapping-geo-point-type)?

Comment: No, I'm about a day old to elasticsearch so I'm not quite sure how to do that. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I've read through quite a bit of documentation but remain confused on how to create the mapping. However, it does seem that I needed to make some adjustments to my query as I have edited. Any hints?

Comment: Have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113439/elasticsearch-geo-distance-filter-with-multiple-locations-in-array-possible/16115189#16115189), if it remains unclear let me know and I will write you an answer on your question.