# multiple locations in cloud search

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I know ElasticSearch offers ability to do multiple locations for a single location field. e.g. [Q on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113439/elasticsearch-geo-distance-filter-with-multiple-locations-in-array-possible)

I was wondering if something like that exists for AWS CloudSearch. for e.g. say you have `location` field with `latlon` type and you can stuff

```
location: [
    {
      "lat": 40.708519,
      "lon": -74.003212
    },
    {
      "lat": 39.752609,
      "lon": -104.998100
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.506321,
      "lon": -0.127140
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudSearch has array versions of many [field types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-index-fields.html) (eg `text-array` and `date-array`) but not for `latlon` type. You would have to make a separate field for each location.

Depending on how many locations per document you have, you may want to look at [dynamic fields](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/using-dynamic-fields.html).

Comment: Thx. I went with dynamic fields.

Comment: @alexroussos any advice when having the same use case but with tons of locations?

Comment: @user2976753 dynamic fields