# Elasticsearch, Filter documents based on different radius for different geopoint field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have ES documents similar to this, I have a location array with a type field.

```
{
  "type": "A/B/C",
  "locations1": [
    {
      "lat": 19.0179332,
      "lon": 72.868069
    },
    {
      "lat": 18.4421771,
      "lon": 73.8585108
    }
  ]
}
```

Type value determines the distance applicable for that location.

Let's say, the allowed distance of query for type A is 10km, for type B is 100km, for type C is 1000km.
Given location L, I want to find all documents which satisfy the distance criteria for that document for the given location and the final result should be sorted by distance.

I am not able to figure out how to use dynamic radius for this. Is it possible or I need to change my document structure similar to this?

EDIT:

I was also thinking of destructing the document locations like this

```
  "locationsTypeA": [
    {
      "lat": 19.0179332,
      "lon": 72.868069
    },
    {
      "lat": 18.4421771,
      "lon": 73.8585108
    }
  ],
  "locationsTypeB": [
    {
      "lat": 19.0179332,
      "lon": 72.868069
    },
    {
      "lat": 18.4421771,
      "lon": 73.8585108
    }
  ],
  "locationsTypeC": [
    {
      "lat": 19.0179332,
      "lon": 72.868069
    },
    {
      "lat": 18.4421771,
      "lon": 73.8585108
    }
  ]
}
```

And then I can use the query

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "10km",
            "locationsTypeA": {
              "lat": 12.5,
              "lon": 18.2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "100km",
            "locationsTypeB": {
              "lat": 12.5,
              "lon": 18.2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "1000km",
            "locationsTypeC": {
              "lat": 12.5,
              "lon": 18.2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: As I am new to Es, I can't think of how to create a query for this, normally I follow this as filter 

```"geo_distance": {
        "distance": "200km",
        "_geoloc": {
          "lat": lat,
          "lon": lon
        }
      }```
But as in this case radius is dynamic, can't find any way to do this in the documentation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the 1st doc structure and the mapping looking like:

```
PUT geoindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "locations": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let's take a random point between Pune and Mumbai to be the origin relative to which we'll perform a scripted geo query using the [`arcDistance` function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-api-reference-shared-org-elasticsearch-index-fielddata.html#painless-api-reference-shared-ScriptDocValues-GeoPoints):

```
GET geoindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": """
                def type = doc['type.keyword'].value;
                def dynamic_distance;
                if (type == "A") {
                  dynamic_distance = 10e3;
                } else if (type == "B") {
                  dynamic_distance = 100e3;
                } else if (type == "C") {
                  dynamic_distance = 1000e3;
                }

                def distance_in_m = doc['locations'].arcDistance(
                  params.origin.lat,
                  params.origin.lon
                );
                
                return distance_in_m < dynamic_distance
              """,
              "params": {
                "origin": {
                  "lat": 18.81531,
                  "lon": 73.49029
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "locations": {
          "lat": 18.81531,
          "lon": 73.49029
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Joe. This is great, it does seem complicated but solves my problem. On your splitting point, I have updated the question with the approach I was thinking, please have a look.

Comment: You're welcome! As to your edit: yea that'd work too but if and only if you make those fields **nested** too. If you have arrays of objects, their properties get flattened and you lose the connections between them.

Comment: I was going through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113439/elasticsearch-geo-distance-filter-with-multiple-locations-in-array-possible), it says in case of an array of locations, the query I added above, iterates and checks all locations in the array and returns true if any matches.

In my case, I only need one condition to be satisfied, either location of type A, B, or C should satisfy the criteria. Am I interpreting it wrong? It would be great if you can point to a link, about flattening of objects in an array,

Comment: My bad -- the `geo_points` don't need to be nested. I was confusing them with regular key-value objects inside of arrays as described in the [official docs](http://nce/current/nested.html#nested-arrays-flattening-objects). I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did the similar but less complex approach

Here's the code:

```
{
            query: {
              bool: {
                must: [
                  {
                    match: {
                      companyName: {
                        query: req.text
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    script: {
                      script: {
                        params: {
                          lat: parseFloat(req.lat),
                          lon: parseFloat(req.lon)
                        },
                        source: "doc['location'].arcDistance(params.lat, params.lon) / 1000 < doc['searchRadius'].value",
                        lang: "painless"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            sort: [
                {
                    _geo_distance: {
                        location: {
                            lat: parseFloat(req.lat),
                            lon: parseFloat(req.lon)
                        },
                        order: "asc",
                        unit:"km"
                    }
                }
            ],
```